# Is it possible to make C/C++ platform independent

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, platform

When Java is made platform independent by introducing JVM, why is it not possible to make C/C++ platform independent by introducing something similar to JVM?

Comment: Its very simple dear.Just write compiler and interpreter for c and c++.

Comment: Java is as platform-independant as the JVM is. And guess in what language the current production-quality JVM has been written ?

Comment: @Youngistan It's called Cint, and it's the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: @SirDarius Actually, IIRC the original reference JVM was written in Java.

Comment: C/C++ *are* platform independent, because you can write a compiler for any platform.  Java just kinda has a *built in compiler*, since the JVM compiles code on the fly.

Comment: @chrylis thanks I stand corrected

Comment: You've asked both "is it possible?" and "why it is not possible?" The second question assumes that the answer to the first question is "no". Which question are you actually asking here?

Comment: are you sure java is platform independent?  If I write the code once and run on two different JVMs on two different (or more) hardware, can I be guaranteed that endianess will not be an issue even if passing data between those JVMs?, reading data from hardware, etc... Hmmm....  I'm not a Java programmer - so just asking...

Comment: @All It seems that there is not a duplicate question. I thought I had already asked this.

Comment: @Eric- yeah it'll run, and if you are using java.awt package , in this case your GUI may change according to the different plateform support, but the execution will be done without re compiling your code...

Comment: You're proposing one more platform to compile C/C++ into.  I don't see how that makes the problem any better.  It's like saying "gosh, there are many competing standards for XYZ; let's solve the problem by introducing a standard for XYZ".

Answer (score 4):

Java is platform independent, but JVM is not, JVM is platform dependent
We have to develope compilers and interpreters to achieve something like JVM.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ are compilers that translate code into binary. As a result, they are platform dependent because different platforms use different binary instruction sets..  If tw0 platforms use the same Assembly language but different binary representations, then telling the compiler to produce an Assembly Language output, will enable the platforms to assemble the results into their individual binary. JVM is like an Assembly Language that is recognized by different platforms. Each platform interprets the JVM in its own way and with its own binary.

```
a = b + c

mov a, R1
mov b, r2
add r1, r2 (putting results in r2)
st r2, c
```

The binary representation of that can be different for different platforms, but a = b + c is "machine independent"

If you were to write a platform independent description of C and get all the platform manufacturors to accept it, then C would also be "platform independent".